# Expected Variance of Y bar

Tags: variance, expected-value, estimators

Why is the expected variance of y bar expressed using the equation?
$Var(\bar Y)=1/n * \theta$
I would expect the following expression.
$Var(\bar Y)=1/n^2 * \theta$

For poisson for example

Comment: By $\theta$ do you mean the individual population variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with $Var(\frac{1}{n}Y)=\frac{1}{n^2}Var(Y)$ with

$Var(\bar{Y})=Var(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n})=Var(\frac{Y_1}{n}+\frac{Y_2}{n}+...+\frac{Y_n}{n})$

When you have a random sapmle then $Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_n$ are i.i.d

Then

$Var(\bar{Y})=Var(\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...Y_n}{n})\\=Var(\frac{Y_1}{n}+\frac{Y_2}{n}+...+\frac{Y_n}{n})\\=Var(\frac{Y_1}{n})+Var(\frac{Y_2}{n})+...+Var(\frac{Y_n}{n})\\=\frac{1}{n^2}[Var(Y_1)+Var(Y_2)+...+Var(Y_n)]\\=\frac{1}{n^2}*n\theta\\=\frac{1}{n}\theta$

Suppose the variance is $\theta$ here

Note Your $Var(\bar{Y})$ is not $Var(\frac{Y+Y+...+Y}{n})$

They are not the same $Y$ which are not independent.